# angular ui-grid event: row selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to enable/disable a button based on the selection of a row on a ui-grid. If there are no rows selected, the button is disabled.

I found this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fNemOQ?p=preview) with the old ng-grid way of firing an event after a row is selected.

```
  $scope.gridOptions = { 

  data: 'myData', 
  selectedItems: $scope.selections,
  enableRowSelection: true,

  afterSelectionChange:function() {
        if ($scope.selections != "" ) {
            $scope.disabled = false;
        } else {
            $scope.disabled = true;
        }
  }
};
```

Unfortunately it does not work, and I have found no sign of such event in the ui-grid [documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api).

How can I achieve that with ui-grid?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In ui-grid, you register a callback function on the event "rowSelectionChanged"

```
 $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
                $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, callbackFunction);
                gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChangedBatch($scope, callbackFunction);
            }
 }

 function callbackFunction(row) { 
    var msg = 'row selected ' + row.isSelected; $log.log(msg); 
 })
```

I think you should take a look at the tutorial page in ui-grid: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection. The API page sucks, in my opinion :(.

Comment: what parameters should I pass to callBack function?

Comment: `gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
        var msg = 'row selected ' + row.isSelected;
        $log.log(msg);
      });`

Comment: API page sucks really, but here is the URL: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.selection.api:PublicApi#events

Answer (score 4):

you can first get all the records selected in the `grid` currently by doing :

```
$scope.rowsSelected = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
```

now we can get the length of this array using :

```
$scope.countRows = $scope.rowsSelected.length;
```

based on `$scope.countRows>0` or `0` you can enable or disable a button using

```
ng-disabled = "countRows"
```

Comment: Thanks @shivisuper Glad it was useful!

Answer (score 2):

```
   $scope.countRows=0;

    $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){

       $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

       gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row){ 
        $scope.countRows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows().length;
        });

       gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChangedBatch($scope, function(row){ 
        $scope.countRows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows().length;
        });
    };
```

In the HTML side you can use some thing like this

```
    <button class="custom-button" ng-disabled="countRows<=0" ng-click="submit()">Details</button>
```